# genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec: array is not a legal constant type

Tags: ros, genmsg, std-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to http://wiki.ros.org/msg, "With the exception of `time` and `duration`, you may declare any built-in type as a constant."

However, when I try this:

```
uint8[3] color
uint8[3] BLACK = {0,0,0}
```

I get:

```
genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec: [...] uint8[3] is not a legal constant type
```

I've also tried `[0,0,0]` and `(0,0,0)` but it didn't make a difference. The error is about the the type, not the value. `std_msgs/UInt8[3]` didn't work either.

Am I messing up the syntax or is it just that ROS msg constants cannot be arrays?

PS1. My goal here is to create *constants* for common RGB colors, such as BLACK, RED, GREEN, BLUE.

PS2. Can I somehow leverage `std_msgs/ColorRGBA` in order to define these constants in my custom message?

---

Update: As Dirk's answer points out, arrays of built-in types are not built-in types themselves. For my usecase (RGB colors), I ended up using a single integer to represent the 3 RGB values. See, for example, http://www.shodor.org/stella2java/rgbint.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244615/genmsg.base.invalidmsgspec:-array-is-not-a-legal-constant-type/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Arrays are *not* built-in types. Therefore you can't define constants of type array.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1